# Squid3 proxy with multiple IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: proxy, squid

I am unable to get Squid 3.5 to respond to any IP but ip1 with this config. I believe the problem is with the use of IPv6, not the way that I am assigning multiple IPs. However, I only have a single IPv4 available to test with.

```
http_port 8121
cache deny all
forwarded_for delete


acl to_ipv6 dst ipv6
http_access allow to_ipv6 !all
tcp_outgoing_address 216.144.232.42 !to_ipv6


acl ip1 myip 216.144.232.**
tcp_outgoing_address 216.144.232.** ip1
acl ip2 myip 2607:fcd0:106:3219::ad76:****
tcp_outgoing_address 2607:fcd0:106:3219::ad76:**** ip 2
acl ip3 myip 2607:fcd0:106:3219::e296:****
tcp_outgoing_address 2607:fcd0:106:3219::e296:**** ip 3


via off
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
http_access deny all
```